# Выполнить сортировку html таблицы до получения html кода

Tags: html, python, get, request, beautiful-soup

Получаю данные по этой [ссылке](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#markets). Код на python. Также использую библиотеку `BeautifulSoup` для последующей обработки HTML кода.

Как мне, перед получением HTML кода страницы, выполнить сортировку таблицы на сайте, например по цене?

```
url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#markets'
html = requests.get(url).text
data = get_data(html)
```

Comment: Под сортировкой я имею ввиду, как если я зашел на сайт и кликнул по заголоку колонки. Все данные бы отсортировались, и изменился бы html код внутри таблицы соответственно. И вот отсортированную таблицу я бы уже выдернул(изменненый html согласно примененной сортировке)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#markets'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

res = (df.assign(pr_num=lambda x: 
                        pd.to_numeric(x['Price'].str.replace(r'[\$,\s\*]',''),
                                      errors='coerce'))
         .sort_values('pr_num', ascending=False))
```

результат:

```
In [268]: print(res)
       #        Source      Pair Volume (24h)      Price Volume (%)   Updated    pr_num
353  354  CoinExchange  CUBE/BTC   $1,568,170  $13064.30      0.03%  Recently  13064.30
13    14          BTCC   BTC/USD  $58,216,900   $7630.00      1.25%  Recently   7630.00
224  225       LakeBTC   BTC/USD   $3,144,690   $7144.04      0.07%  Recently   7144.04
251  252       Bitinka   BTC/ARS   $2,599,470   $7087.53      0.06%  Recently   7087.53
170  171          BCEX   NAS/BTC   $4,433,300   $7057.71      0.09%  Recently   7057.71
..   ...           ...       ...          ...        ...        ...       ...       ...
280  281         Bit-Z   XAS/BTC   $2,230,820   $6297.18      0.05%  Recently   6297.18
279  280   BtcTrade.im   ETC/BTC   $2,270,590   $6287.73      0.05%  Recently   6287.73
291  292          OKEx    OF/BTC   $2,112,840   $6278.22      0.05%  Recently   6278.22
369  370        Hotbit  BZNT/BTC   $1,453,500   $6272.91      0.03%  Recently   6272.91
193  194          BCEX   ANS/BTC   $3,664,540   $5950.85      0.08%  Recently   5950.85

[400 rows x 8 columns]
```

если нужен HTML:

```
res.to_html(r'c:/temp/res.html')
```

результат для первых 10 строк:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>Pair</th>
      <th>Volume (24h)</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Volume (%)</th>
      <th>Updated</th>
      <th>pr_num</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>353</th>
      <td>354</td>
      <td>CoinExchange</td>
      <td>CUBE/BTC</td>
      <td>$1,568,170</td>
      <td>$13064.30</td>
      <td>0.03%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>13064.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>13</th>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>BTCC</td>
      <td>BTC/USD</td>
      <td>$58,216,900</td>
      <td>$7630.00</td>
      <td>1.25%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>7630.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>224</th>
      <td>225</td>
      <td>LakeBTC</td>
      <td>BTC/USD</td>
      <td>$3,144,690</td>
      <td>$7144.04</td>
      <td>0.07%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>7144.04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>251</th>
      <td>252</td>
      <td>Bitinka</td>
      <td>BTC/ARS</td>
      <td>$2,599,470</td>
      <td>$7087.53</td>
      <td>0.06%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>7087.53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>170</th>
      <td>171</td>
      <td>BCEX</td>
      <td>NAS/BTC</td>
      <td>$4,433,300</td>
      <td>$7057.71</td>
      <td>0.09%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>7057.71</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>223</th>
      <td>224</td>
      <td>BtcTrade.im</td>
      <td>LTC/BTC</td>
      <td>$3,146,020</td>
      <td>$7044.13</td>
      <td>0.07%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>7044.13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>146</th>
      <td>147</td>
      <td>Bit-Z</td>
      <td>GXS/BTC</td>
      <td>$5,608,050</td>
      <td>$6958.11</td>
      <td>0.12%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>6958.11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>385</th>
      <td>386</td>
      <td>LBank</td>
      <td>PNT/BTC</td>
      <td>$1,385,290</td>
      <td>$6904.87</td>
      <td>0.03%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>6904.87</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>264</th>
      <td>265</td>
      <td>Negocie Coins</td>
      <td>BTC/BRL</td>
      <td>$2,487,080</td>
      <td>$6898.36</td>
      <td>0.05%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>6898.36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>387</th>
      <td>388</td>
      <td>Trade By Trade</td>
      <td>DASH/BTC</td>
      <td>$1,378,990</td>
      <td>$6894.70</td>
      <td>0.03%</td>
      <td>Recently</td>
      <td>6894.70</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

PS чтобы удалить созданный столбец `pr_num`:

```
res = res.drop('pr_num', axis=1)

In [272]: res
Out[272]:
       #        Source      Pair Volume (24h)      Price Volume (%)   Updated
353  354  CoinExchange  CUBE/BTC   $1,568,170  $13064.30      0.03%  Recently
13    14          BTCC   BTC/USD  $58,216,900   $7630.00      1.25%  Recently
224  225       LakeBTC   BTC/USD   $3,144,690   $7144.04      0.07%  Recently
251  252       Bitinka   BTC/ARS   $2,599,470   $7087.53      0.06%  Recently
170  171          BCEX   NAS/BTC   $4,433,300   $7057.71      0.09%  Recently
..   ...           ...       ...          ...        ...        ...       ...
280  281         Bit-Z   XAS/BTC   $2,230,820   $6297.18      0.05%  Recently
279  280   BtcTrade.im   ETC/BTC   $2,270,590   $6287.73      0.05%  Recently
291  292          OKEx    OF/BTC   $2,112,840   $6278.22      0.05%  Recently
369  370        Hotbit  BZNT/BTC   $1,453,500   $6272.91      0.03%  Recently
193  194          BCEX   ANS/BTC   $3,664,540   $5950.85      0.08%  Recently

[400 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Сейчас буду разбираться с кодом и библиотеку осваивать, слышал о ней раньше но не использовал.

Comment: Очень много полезного, спасибо, уже сижу разбираюсь!

Comment: @DmitrySharko, рад помочь! Если будут вопросы по Pandas - задавайте их здесь на SO... ;-)